# fadeIn() does not make web page scroll at the right position

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, slideshow, fadein

I use jQuery to implement the slide show animation.
The html looks like:

```
<div class="slideshow pointer">
  <img class="next" src="img1">
  ...
</div>
```

I use jQuery to find the next image, fadeOut the previous one and fadeIn the next one. This slideshow part is made visible by a click action of a image thumb. When the first image is loaded, the webpage will scroll to the right place (a proper position to show the image).
But when I click to show the next image, the webpage scroll to a different place, and click next, the webpage scroll to a second different place. The address stays at 'www.xxx.home.html#/books/01/'. And I use another javascript function to make this address display the webpage at the right position.
I have checked that when I click to show next image, there is only this function used, no other function that would cause a slideDown or scroll action (not 100% sure). I am wondering if fadeIn() action does something more than I expect, e.g. some scroll action?
The javascript code:

```
$('body').on('click', '.slideshow img', function(e){ 
  var thisimg = $(this);  
  var thisss = thisimg.parent();  
  var totimgs = thisss.find("img").length;  
  if (totimgs > 1){  
    var thisindex = thisimg.index();  
    var x  = e.pageX - 240;  
    if (x < 240 || x > 600) {  
      if (x < 240) {  
        var nextindex = thisindex - 1;  
        if (nextindex < 0) {
          nextindex = totimgs - 1;
        }
      } else if (x > 600) {
        var nextindex = thisindex + 1;
        if (nextindex > totimgs - 1) {
          nextindex = 0;
        }
      } else {
        nextindex = thisindex;
      }
      thisimg.fadeOut(500);
      var nextss = thisss.find("img:nth-child(" + (nextindex + 1) + ")");
      nextss.fadeIn(500);
    }
  }
});
```

Can anyone give the reason why? Or there is something else I need to check what makes this scroll?

Comment: You could try preventing the default action in your click handler using `e.preventdefault()` or `return false` - If you can put together a fiddle it would help

Comment: Are you changing the hash of the url? I think that could cause the page to try and scroll.

Comment: No I didn't change url, and `e.preventdefault()` does not help. I found that the first two images have this problem. When comes to the third image, though the position is not right, when click next, the position doesn't change any more.

Comment: I put an alert() in callback function of `fadeIn()`. And I find that this alert() comes out before `fadeIn()` action finished. @Kolby, do you know any reason about this?